# Express: limit request size

Tags: node.js, parsing, express

To limit the request size to 123 bytes, I use the following which works fine:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: 123
}));
```

To parse all requests **except for** "/specialRequest", I use the following which works fine as well:

```
app.use(/^(?!\/specialRequest)/,bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

But I fail to limit the request size of **all** requests to 123 and parse all requests **except for** "/specialRequest". Here is my current code:

```
app.use(/^(?!\/specialRequest)/,bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: 123
}));
```

However, this only limits the requests size for requests different than "/specialRequest". How can I limit the request size of **all** requests to 123 and parse all requests **except for** "/specialRequest"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the request body for `/specialRequest` to be limited in size but not parsed, you can use [`bodyParser.raw()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions). In that case, `req.body` will be a `Buffer` instance that contains the request body as-is (unparsed, although it will be inflated if it was presented as gzipped or deflated data; this behaviour can be disabled through its options).

You need to declare it before you insert the `bodyParser.urlencoded()` middleware:

```
app.post('/specialRequest', bodyParser.raw({ limit : 123, type : '*/*' }), function(req, res) {
  ...
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: 123
}));
```

Comment: But this approach would not limit the size of '/specialRequest' to 123?

Comment: Yes, that is my intention, however adding bodyParser.raw({ limit : 123 }) does not have any effect. I put it before bodyParser.urlencoded() but there are no errors and warnings displayed.

Comment: @BJPrim new edit, check again (I added `type : '*/*'`) so `bodyParser` will apply the limit to all mime types)

Comment: Thank you, now I got everything running!